# Anonymous method return type casting

Tags: c#, casting, anonymous-methods

I have an object "ConnectableProperty" that hooks up one property to another, and requires I feed it Func. Now I have 2 types at the moment - Scalar and Color. Both are castable to each other via explicit operators. For some reason I can't feed a `Func<double, double, Scalar>` to `Func<double, double Color>`, even though Scalar can cast to Color. What's the deal?

To clarify, i've added the code. Note that connectable properties are the "inputs". The outputs (that can be plugged in) are Methods that have that  signature.

Here's ConnectableProperty

```
public sealed class ConnectableProperty<T> : IEquatable<T>, IGetXY<T> where T : IValue<T>
{
    private T _value;
    public T Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }

    public INode ParentNode { get; private set; }
    public ValueConnection<T> Connection { get; set; }
    public INode ConnectionFrom { get { return !IsConnected ? null : Connection.FromNode; } }
    public bool IsConnected { get { return Connection == null; } }

    public ConnectableProperty(INode parentNode, T value)
    {
        ParentNode = parentNode;
        _value = value;
    }

    public T GetXY(double x, double y)
    {
        return IsConnected 
            ? Connection.FromValue(x, y) 
            : _value;
    }

    public void Connect(INode fromNode, Func<double, double, T> getXY)
    {
        Connection = new ValueConnection<T>(fromNode, ParentNode, getXY, this);
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        Connection = null;
    }

    public bool Equals(T other)
    {
        return _value.Equals(other);
    }

    public static implicit operator T(ConnectableProperty<T> connectableProperty)
    {
        return connectableProperty._value;
    }
}
```

And ValueConnection:

```
public class ValueConnection<T>
{
    public INode FromNode { get; private set; }
    public INode ToNode { get; private set; }

    public Func<double, double, T> FromValue { get; private set; }
    public ConnectableProperty<T> ToValue { get; private set; }

    public ValueConnection(INode fromNode, INode toNode, Func<double, double, T> fromValue, ConnectableProperty<T> toValue)
    {
        // TODO: Implement INPC type thing

        FromNode = fromNode;
        ToNode = toNode;

        FromValue = fromValue;
        ToValue = toValue; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u give example how are u doing it right now?

Comment: Can you post your objects?  If the cast is only possible explicitly then I don't see how the Func can work.

Comment: maybe if there were some sort of inheritance, or interface implementation you could feed the scalar func to the color one, but not like this

Comment: As an aside: `public bool IsConnected { get { return Connection == null; } }`  Are you sure?

Comment: Ha. Good find. Although it's the basic plumbing - this Func one is doing my head in, unless I make everything output a single type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you won't be able to perform that conversion directly, and I wouldn't expect to be able to - but you could easily write a pair of methods to perform it for you:

```
public Func<double, double, Scalar> ConvertFunc(Func<double, double, Color func)
{
    return (x, y) => (Scalar) func(x, y);
}

public Func<double, double, Color> ConvertFunc(Func<double, double, Scalar func)
{
    return (x, y) => (Color) func(x, y);
}
```

When you've got a delegate which is meant to return a particular type, that has to be able to be invoked *directly* and return a value of the appropriate type. The caller shouldn't have to know that even though they've got a `Func<X>`, if they want to get an `X` out of it, they'll need to cast the result to an `X`.

Comment: Can one just declare their own 'Func' type and specify that the third type parameter is 'out' (covariance). Would that work?

Comment: @zespri: The result parameter of `Func<T>` is already covariant in .NET 4, but covariance doesn't work with user-defined conversions.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. I think, in context, the most elegant solution may be to have a few static methods in a ValueConverter class that convert to/from.

Comment: Indeed i'm using a IGetXY<T> interface anyway, so i'll just make said converter implement that for Scalar, Color, etc. to keep things neat.

Answer (score 6):

Jon is right; just to add to that:

First, the reason this doesn't work is because there is no place where the conversion exists. Suppose you have:

```
Func<int> f1 = ()=>1;
Func<double> f2 = f1;
```

Suppose that were legal. Somewhere, the C# compiler has to generate an *instruction* that converts an int to a double. Where? Not in the lambda; that thing has to return an int when f1 is called. But not in f2 either, because f1 is *reference identical* to f1. There are two possible solutions: make it illegal, or make this actually mean:

```
f2 = ()=>(double)f1();
```

so that f1 and f2 are not reference identical anymore. We've chosen the first solution.

Second, this is legal in C# 4 if the return types have an implicit *reference* conversion between them. We don't need to emit any instructions for an implicit reference conversion; it is legal without any special code.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't do the job simply using explicit cast inside of the function body? Then u can use just one type of the function - no casting needed